# Calculate $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ for $X=\mathbb{V}(xy)\subset\mathbb{A}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is the ring of germ of regular functions $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ when $X=\mathbb{V}(xy)\subset\mathbb{A}^2$ and for $p=(0,0)$ and $p=(0,1)$?

I am not clear about the definition of $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$, so it will be greatly appreciated if you can show me in detail how to calculate the above two rings so I may get a better understanding of the concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, for a variety $V \subset \mathbb A^2$, the ring $\mathcal O_{V,p}$ is just the localization of $k[x,y]/I_V$ at the prime ideal corresponding to $p$.

So if $p=(0,0)$, you localize at $\mathfrak m=(x,y)$. This means you are allowed to divide by everything outside $\mathfrak m$. But in this case, the ideal is contained in $\mathfrak m$, so "nothing changes", in the sense that the generators of the ideal is not affected. The elements of the local ring are now fractions $\frac{f}{g}$ where $g \not\in (x,y)$.

However, if you localize at $(x,y-1)$ (corresponding to $p=(0,1)$), then $y$ becomes a unit, so the local ring is $k[x,y]/(x) \approx k[y]$ (localized at $(y-1)$). This reflects the fact that near $p$, the variety just looks like a line, whereas near $(0,0)$, the variety looks like a cross.

Comment: I don't think I agree with this. $\mathcal O_{V,p}$ must depend on $V$, whereas what you wrote in the first paragraph only depends on $p$. (Typo?) Moreover, I don't understand the "nothing changes" comment. As a concrete example, consider an element like $x-1$: this is not invertible in $k[V]$ but it is invertible in $\mathcal O_{V,p}$.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Thanks for the comment. The first thing you commented on was indeed a typo. I've corrected it. I agree I was being somewhat imprecise - I've edited the answer.

Comment: OK, now it makes more sense to me!

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your answer:(..In the first part, why does $\gcd(g,xy)=1$? I think $g$ is any polynomial not belongs to $(x,y)$, which not necessarily has $\gcd(g,xy)=1$. In the second part, I don't understand the words 'then $y$ becomes a unit'

Comment: @hxhxhx88 You are right about the gcd part, I've corrected it. For the second, when localizing, you are allowed to divide by $y$.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer, hi, I still have some confusion. In the second case, are you suggesting the local ring is isomorphic to $k[x]$ localized at $(x)$? Why can we change from localizing at $(x, y-1)$ to at $(x)$? You said since we can divide by $y$, it becomes a unit, which I think implies $(xy)=(x)$, so the coordinate ring $k[x,y]/(xy)$ becomes $k[x,y]/(x)$. But how does this affect the ring at which we are localizing, i.e. $(x, y-1)$? What about that we can divide by $y+1, y-3$, etc?

Comment: @hxhxhx88 Hi. I noticed I had a typo in my answer. Of course, when we divide out by $(x)$, we are left with only $y$, so that $k[x,y]/(x)$ (localized at $(x,y-1)$ is isomorphic to $k[y]$ (localized at $(y-1)$).

Comment: @FredrikMeyer,clear now, thanks!